# Вставляю массив в другой, но информация не читабельна

Tags: php

```
                'one' => true,
                'two' =>  array(
                      $ar
                )
            );
```

Вместо информации в массиве (а там еще один массив) на выходе получается:

```
                'one' => true,
                'two' =>  array(
                      arrayarray
                )
            );
```

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте просто вот так:

```
$array = [
    "1" => "PHP code tester Sandbox Online",  
    "foo" => "bar", 5 , 5 => 89009, 
    "case" => "Random Stuff: " . rand(100,999),
    "PHP Version" => phpversion()
];
              
$array2 = [
    'one' => true,
    'two' =>  $array
];
```

Чтобы вложить один массив в другой - нужно просто указать массив как элемент в желаемом массиве и он вложится.

В примере выше получится вот такой вывод в print_r($array2):

```
Array
(
    [one] => 1
    [two] => Array
        (
            [1] => PHP code tester Sandbox Online
            [foo] => bar
            [2] => 5
            [5] => 89009
            [case] => Random Stuff: 512
            [PHP Version] => 7.4.7
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот правильная структура вложенного массива:

```
$array = [
        '1' => 'one',
        '2' => 'two',
        '3' => [
            '1' => 'one',
            '2' => 'two',
        ]
];

var_dump ($array);
```

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  string(3) "one"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "two"
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [1]=>
    string(3) "one"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "two"
  }
}
```

array() и [] - одно и тоже. Использовать [] можно с версии 5.4